# www and http works but not https in AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to deploy a web application which is deployed in port 80 and I am able to access the website from www.ajaykalkoti.space and http://ajaykalkoti.space .

If I try to access the https://ajaykalkoti.space It returns 403 Error.The Request could not be satisfied.What should be my entry in Route 53.I have attached a screenshot of the below entries.

I am not using Load Balancer as I guess it gets charged.

Please guide me.

---

> Route 53 Table

[image]

---

> A Record

[image]

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you are running an HTTPS server? Are you really running it on port 80? Why not on port 443, the standard port for HTTPS? If you are running it on port 80, why are you trying to access it on port 443?

Comment: I am running a Spring Boot Application,Should I need to make it run on 443?

Answer (score 0):

Use this AWS guide:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-an-instance.html

And you should configure 443 port in /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:

```
Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName ajaykalkoti.space
  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/ssl.error.log
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/ssl.log combined

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile PATH_TO_CERT.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile PATH_TO_KEY.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile PATH_TO_CHAIN.ca-bundle

  SSLProtocol -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
  SSLProxyProtocol -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2

  SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:AES:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA

  SSLProxyCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:AES:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA

  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass        / http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

as example

And enable 443 port in instance security group